# Pulling in Structure entries as radio button options in Sprout Forms

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I have a form created with Sprout Forms with a custom template to override the HTML. This form needs to pull in plan type information from a structure section that already exists.

I added the structure entries to the form in the template, but they currently aren't hooked up to form so when I hit submit. How can I hook this up so that when a user selects a plan type it will register with Sprout Forms?

I could try and create these fields in the form builder, but the way it's set up it's easier for us and the client to pull the information from the existing entries.

Answer (score 1):

[Sprout Forms](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/) v2.3.0 adds front-end field support for Entries, Categories, and Tags Relations fields.

By default, the fields will display a multi-select field on the front-end. If the limit is set to 1, they will display a dropdown field.

The fields are designed to work for simple use cases. If you have hundreds or thousands of entries, you may need to consider a custom front-end field type for your scenario.